# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when I'm loading a self signed Jar in a local webpage

Tags: java, applet, japplet, invocationtargetexception

I have a very simple Test program that just opens up a JFrame and I want to open it in browser. I know I have to self sign it to open it but it throws just this error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I have signed the jar with the JARMAKER

My HTML to load the jar:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Inhalt der Webseite</p>

    <applet code=Simple_Frame.class
        archive="Simple_Frame2.jar"
        width="120" height="120">
</applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

The simple Test program:

```
    import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Flex on 22.10.14.
 */
public class Start extends Applet{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Simple_Frame ex = new Simple_Frame();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}


import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Simple_Frame extends JFrame {

    public Simple_Frame() {

        setTitle("Simple example");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

How can I open a Jar in a webpage on my localhost to test it without that error and what does this error mean?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing. 3) That HTML is invalid.  It declares itself as HTML 4.01, but the `applet` element was deprecated by then.

Answer (score 1):

```
<applet code=Simple_Frame.class
    archive="Simple_Frame2.jar"
    width="120" height="120">
```

The first thing that jumps out at me, is that `Simple_Frame` is **not an applet.**  The `Start` class is though.

```
<applet code=Start
    archive="Simple_Frame2.jar"
    width="120" height="120">
```

Another tip is that `InvocationTargetException` is usually a wrapper for another more specific exception.  Always copy/paste the full error and exception output!